# Stratum proxy on Windows

Tags: altcoin, server, windows, stratum, proxy

I am looking to do solo mining on a SHA-256 altcoin by purchasing hashrate from NiceHash. I have the client set up on a Windows Server 2016 VPS and the blockchain is synced. For NiceHash to point the miners to me, I need to offer a stratum+tcp connection.

I have attempted to set up a mining pool using NOMP, but ran into countless errors that - when fixed - generated even more abstract errors, so dead end there.

Essentially what I am looking for is a proxy (?) that will get work from my client (JSON-RPC works and is potentially reachable from other servers) and deliver it to the NiceHash miners over stratum+tcp. I need no payout system or similar. 
Is there any ready windows ( /java /...) program that covers this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is searching this in the future: CoiniumServ can be self-compiled from the github source and runs on windows.

Comment: awesome! I was looking for exactly that